# Node JS Connect - Can You Call '.use' Dynamically?

Tags: node.js, express, connect

I have the follow code:

```
connect().
   use(connect.vhost(virtualHostName, staticServerApp))...
```

If I wanted to add another virtual host dynamically, say, based on an app configuration change, how would I do that?

Comment: You should probably make your own implementation of that middleware that looks up vhosts dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern:

```
var app = connect();

for(var uri in Conf.VIRTUAL_HOST){
    app.use(connect.vhost(Conf.VIRTUAL_HOST[uri], staticServerApp));
}
```

Appears to work.